How to Handle the code_interpreter Tool in OpenAI's Assistant Client Locally?
I am working with OpenAI's .NET client to create a custom assistant that uses tools. I referenced the example from OpenAI's GitHub repository (link), where tools like getNameOfFamilyMemberTool, file_search, and code_interpreter are defined.
In my implementation, I followed the pattern shown in the example:
Tools = { getNameOfFamilyMemberTool, new FileSearchToolDefinition(), new CodeInterpreterToolDefinition() }

In this setup:

getNameOfFamilyMemberTool is implemented locally and handled in a switch case.
file_search and code_interpreter appear to be system-defined tools that I cannot fully control or customize.

Problem
When I handle updates from the assistant and encounter a RequiredActionUpdate for code_interpreter, there are two scenarios:

If I do not handle code_interpreter:
Omitting the handling entirely results in the following error:
"Expected tool outputs for call_ids"


If I provide dummy output:
When I return a placeholder ToolOutput for code_interpreter, it avoids the error, but produces a dummy, non-functional result:
else if (requiredActionUpdate.FunctionName == "code_interpreter")
{
    // Handle code_interpreter with placeholder
    outputsToSubmit.Add(new ToolOutput(requiredActionUpdate.ToolCallId, "Not implemented yet"));
}



Question
What is the correct way to handle the code_interpreter tool if its implementation is internal to OpenAI?
Relevant Code for Context
Here’s the part of my implementation where I handle required actions and submit outputs:
if (update is RequiredActionUpdate requiredActionUpdate)
{
    if (requiredActionUpdate.FunctionName == "code_interpreter")
    {
        // Handle code_interpreter with a placeholder
        outputsToSubmit.Add(new ToolOutput(requiredActionUpdate.ToolCallId, "Not implemented yet"));
    }
    else
    {
        // Generic tool handling logic
        var result = await _mediator.Send(requiredActionUpdate.GetCommand(), cancellationToken);
        outputsToSubmit.Add(new ToolOutput(requiredActionUpdate.ToolCallId, result?.ToString()));
    }
}

// Submit tool outputs
if (outputsToSubmit.Count > 0)
{
    asyncUpdates = _client.SubmitToolOutputsToRunStreamingAsync(currentRun.ThreadId, currentRun.Id, outputsToSubmit, cancellationToken);
}


You don't need to handle code_interpreter locally but you have to perform function_calling locally if you did the configuration. The following repo can be  referred but it is done by Python.
https://github.com/ideabosque/openai_assistant_engine
